# Jquery clearing data before new data loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that displays data in it.  I have created a button that allows the user to select a date, and then display the data for that date in the table. I am unsure how to clear out the original data before the new data displays.  At this point it's just displaying what was originally selected plus the new data.  Here's my code:

```
<script>    
   $(".spiffdate-btn").click(function(){
   var correctId = $("ul.spiff_tabs li.active a").attr('data-id');


   var startDate = $("#startDate").val();
   if (startDate == "") {

   } else {
       if (correctId == "delayedspiff")
       {
           $.get("@Url.Action("DelayedSpiff", "Dashboard")", { startDate: startDate }, function (data) {
               $('#details').html(data);

           });  


       } else if (correctId = "instantspiff") {

           $.get("@Url.Action("InstantSpiff", "Dashboard")", { startDate: startDate }, function (data) {
               $('#details').html(data);

           });

       }           
   }     
 });   
</script>
```

How do I clear before $('#details').html(data);?

UPDATE:

This is how the data loads when the view loads for the first time:

```
function pullDetails(carrierId, startDate, status, divid) {
    $.get("@Url.Action("getDelayedSpiffOrderDetails", "Dashboard")",
        { carrierId: carrierId, startDate: startDate, status: status },
        function (data) {               
            $('#' + divid + ' .submitted_details').html(data);
            $('#' + divid + ' .submitted_details').html(data);
            $('#' + divid).removeClass('carrier-hide');

        });
}
```

How do I get it to clear this data when I run the new data?

Comment: just simply set it to nothing ('')

Comment: `$('#details').html("");` then  `$('#details').html(data);`

Comment: @AlexeiDarmin I kind of left something out.  I have jquery that runs when the view first loads that loads data.  This data is reloading when the view loads a second time with the n ew data.  I need to clear out this initial data, but it loads everytime the view loads.  I made an update to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

Before assigning data result to table, clear the contents using empty().

```
$(".spiffdate-btn").click(function(){
    $('#details').empty();
    $('#details').html(data);
});
```

Comment: RGS please see my above comment.

Answer (score 1):

just simply set it to nothing

```
document.getElementById('details').innerHTML= '';
```

Comment: Dane, please see my above comment.